# Error because argument for ArrayLen may be empty

Tags: sql, web-applications, coldfusion

When ArrayLen is called with an element that is null, it throws an error. How do you make it return 0?

```
The value '' cannot be converted to a number.

The error occurred in D:/Resource/WWW/DEV/ww1dev.cwtvacations.com/welcome_survey/welcome_survey_question_builder.cfm: line 12

10 :    <cfset curPage = SESSION.thisPage />
11 : 
12 :    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage])#" index="curQuestion">
13 :        <cfif (SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage][curQuestion].SectionID eq 4 AND SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.AirlineID neq 0)   <!--- Ask airline questions, if airline known  --->
14 :                OR (SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage][curQuestion].SectionID neq 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple things you can do. You can use a ternary operator and assign the whole thing to a variable:

`upperBound = isNull(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]) ? 0 : ArrayLen(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]);`

Or you can check it before hand. However, it appeared odd that you are specifying a specific element of an array as the array. i.e. `SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]` does `pagesQuestions[]` contain the array or is it the array? If it is the array, remove the `[curParge]` index.

Comment: Could you please give the whole thing, I tried <cfset upperBound = isNull(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]) ? 0 : ArrayLen(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]); /> and it didn't work. Without the cfset it says "upperBound undefined"

Comment: `<cfset upperBound = isNull(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]) ? 0 : ArrayLen(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]) />

<cfloop from="1" to="#upperBound#" index="curQuestion">`

What version of CF are you using?

Comment: 8 and it says "Invalid token ? found on line 12 at column 84. " when I try your idea

Comment: It also says variable ISNULL is undefined

Comment: `<cfif isArray(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]) >
  <cfset upperBound = arrayLen(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.pagesQuestions[curPage]) />
<cfelse>
  <cfset upperBound = 0 />
</cfif>`